# Can the DOM be differentially updated?

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, libraries

First and foremost, I've done extensive research about this, under different names that I think could apply such as "Javascript differential templating", "Javascript update DOM without reparsing", "Javascript render UI using deltas" and other variations. Pardon me if I missed an existing thread that covers my question.

Essentially, I would first like to know if most DOM parsers in browsers do the following already, even though I'm fairly sure the answer is no: do they update the DOM differentially (i.e. only the nodes that have changed in the same tree since the last update) when a node is modified? Like I said, I figure the answer is no and they actually reparse and rerender the updated node and everything in its tree.

Which brings me to my question: is there any Javascript library that allows to manage differential updates to a data model and to the DOM?

I realize I might not be really clear about this, so I will provide some code to explain what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/btZ3e/6/

In that example, I have an "event queue" (which is really a timeline) with events in it. UserEvents all have a unique ID. The way it works now is that UserEvents can execute() and undo(), in the former they modify data in memory (myAppManager.dataModel) and append a <p> in the DOM while in the latter they undo these changes. (Each UserEvent's undo() is  defined within the execute() of the same UserEvent as to allow more flexibility, one could consider moving events around independently)

Then, there is myAppManager.render() :

```
 var myAppManager = new function () {
     this.dataModel = {
         someValue: 0,
         disableButton: false
     };

     this.render = function () {
         $('#displaysomevalue').text(this.dataModel.someValue);
         $('#go').prop('disabled', this.dataModel.disableButton)
     }
 }
```

How would it be possible (is it at all?) that myAppManager.render() only updates what has changed since the last update? I reckon this would mean that I would have to have some sort of differentiation system in my data model too. Ultimately I'm wondering about this because I'm gonna be receiving multiple new UserEvents per second (let's say 20-30 per second at worst?)  via websockets and I was wondering if I would need to rerender my whole UI for every new piece of data I get. I investigated into Javascript templates to see how they do it, and it seems they all just go this route:

```
document.getElementById('someTemplateContainer').innerHTML = someTemplateEngine.getHtmlOutput();
```

I doubt however they need to refresh as often as I need to in some instances. Is there prior work on this? Did I miss anything? Thank you very much!

Comment: I haven't looked at it closely, but this is what ReactJS purports to do: http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html (calculate diffs in your templates). Not sure if that's helpful at all...

Comment: @AlexMcp Woah, this really looks promising. I was making this kind of post because I was strongly hoping such a thing was already existing and I had just somehow missed it. I'm just looking at the ToDo example on their site now and I really like it so far, I'll look more into it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Backbone.js, as an example, does this is that models (name:value pairs basically) are backed by a view/template, and that models have events associated with them like `change`. Let's say you have a `<ul>` where each `<li>` is one Backbone view, backed by a model.

You could bind every model's `change` event to re-render its own view (and ONLY its own view). So when the 5th `<li>` gets its name changed, it will re-render just the contents of that `<li>`, and the rest of the `<ul>` is undisturbed.

That lets only new or updated models have their DOM nodes touched and updated.

The difference is that you don't need to know 'what parts of the whole `<ul>` have changed and just render those', because you've actually decomposed the problem to a series of smaller ones, each of which are responsible for their own rendering and updating logic. (I'm sure other frameworks have similar patterns, and you can do them in vanilla JS too no doubt)

Comment: That really seems the way to go! I believe the ReactJS you mentioned above works that way, with a bit of extra syntactic sugar added.